# Arrange a list in the sequence order

Tags: php, sorting, sequence

I need a logic for the sequence order for the list

We have a list of array values 6,5,4,3,2,1. In this list I need to replace 5 as 2. Then I need to sequence the order.

For example :
Take a 5 in the list and replace the value as 2

Then now we have a list like this 6,2,4,3,2,1 So now in this list we don't have a sequence of order.
 I need to solve the sequence orde in the below method

First we need to check if(5 < 2) the result is NO
So we need to take the next value of in the list 4
Now we need to check like this

Step 1:

if(4 < 2) ->> (here 2 is replaced value 4 is next value in the list)
 No

then we need to add +1 to that number 4+1  = 5
 Now the list we have looking like this 6,2,5,3,2,1

Step 2 :

Then we need to check take next number 3, then check
if(3 < 2)  ->> (here 2 is replaced value 3 is next value in the list)
    No 
 then we need to add +1 to that number 3+1   = 4
   Now the list we have looking like this 6,2,5,4,2,1

Step 3:

Then we need to check take next number 2, then check
if(2 < 2)  ->> (here 2 is replaced value 2 is next value in the list)
    No 
 then we need to add +1 to that number 2+1   = 3
   Now the list we have looking like this 6,2,5,4,3,1

Step 4:

Then we need to check take next number 2, then check
if(1 < 2)  ->> (here 2 is replaced value 1 is next value in the list)
    Yes 
 then exit from the loop.

Please help me on this method to solve the sequence order

I tried with below code in PHP

```
$list = array(6,5,4,3,2,1);
$currentval = 5;
$replaceval = 2;


foreach (array_keys($list) as $index => $key) {
    // first, get current item
    echo $items = $list[$key];
    // now get next item in array
        $next = null;
        if($currentval >= $items){
            if (array_key_exists($index + 1, array_keys($list))) {
                $next = $list[array_keys($list)[$index + 1]];
            }
        }
        echo "Next".$next."<br>";

}
```

Comment: _For example : Take a 5 in the list and replace the value as 2_ here start values could be different ?, if different you want to do these steps on the values, based in the index/position of the values under consideration ?

Comment: The start value I can take any value in the list it could be 5 or 3 or 6

Comment: At start `if(5 < 2)` this is false we go to next value, now `if(4 < 2)` is false but we add 1 to the 4, and all the next `false` we add number and replace values but when `if(1 < 2)` is `true` we replace 2 and put 1 at the last and the loop ends ? is that right ?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

im new in programming, i'll try to answer. Maybe something like this is what you need

```
$indexCurrent = null;
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($list); $i++) { 
    if ($list[$i] == $currentval) {
        if ($list[$i] >= $replaceval) {
            $list[$i] = $replaceval;
            $indexCurrent = $i;
        }
    } elseif ($indexCurrent != $i) {
        if ($list[$i] >= $replaceval) {
            $list[$i] = $list[$i]+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the above code is not working for this $currentval and $replaveval

$list = array(6,5,4,3,2,1);
$currentval = 6;
$replaceval = 1;

Comment: what $list value do you want if $currentval = 6; $replaceval = 1 ?

Comment: The result should be like this 1,6,5,4,3,2

Comment: Replace ($indexCurrent != null) to ($indexCurrent != $i), the code has been edited